# How to upload object from JavaScript to Rest API

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Rest API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Services/Image/Upload")]
public string Upload([FromBody]GalleryItem galleryItem)
{
    try
    {
        var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GalleryPath"].ToString();

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(appSettings + galleryItem.KeyCode + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(galleryItem.Base64);
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
        return "OK";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();

    }
}
```

and I call it from my Javascript client like:

```
var galleryItem = new Object();
galleryItem.Base64 = base64;
galleryItem.KeyCode = '1234';
url = "http://my domain name/api/Services/Image/Upload";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',         
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(galleryItem),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'text/plain',
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('Image saved successfully !');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        $('#error').html('Error: ' + err);
}
});
```

my model:

```
public class GalleryItem
{
    public string Base64 { get; set; }
    public string KeyCode { get; set; }
}
```

I a testing this via a mobile device as I am taking image from camera to send up.

Nothing appears to happen?  I just 'Error: error'?

thanks

ADDITIONAL:
After porting to a test script (wished I had done that sooner) I found the error is this:

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Though why I am unsure as I am calling another method from that api with no issues

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Thank God!

I changed the url to relative:

```
url = "/api/Services/Image/Upload";
```

without prefixing with domain name.

it must have got confused and thought it needed cors? (guess here)

Comment: Everyone - thank you all for trying to help me.  It made me feel not alone! :)

Comment: It's okay to accept your own answer to a question. Take credit for the troubleshooting.